# I am trying to export the particular function from one file and import into another, but unable to export the functions, any help would be nice

Tags: reactjs

```
class Utility extends Component {
  state = {
    userAnswer: null, //current users answer
    currentIndex: 0, //current questions index
    options: [], //the four options
    quizEnd: false,
    score: 0,
    disabled: true,
  };

  handleChange = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    this.setState({
      currentIndex: this.state.currentIndex,
      [name]: value,
    });
  };

  indexHandler = (index) => {
    const { userAnswer, answer, score } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      currentIndex: index,
    });
    };
}
```

Is there any way to export the functions initialized inside the class? as here
handleChange and indexHandler. (This is just a code snippet and render and return functions are declared ahead in the code.)

Comment: No, you would have to declare them outside the function and use `export`.

Comment: Okay, so that's the only way I guess. Thanks